# How to solve system of 2 non-linear equations?

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, nonlinear-system

I want to solve system of 2 equations, were all variables below are given except 2 unknowns: $V_0, \sigma_V$. It should be easy to solve numerically system of 2 non-linear equations with 2 unknowns:
\begin{cases} 
 E_0 = V_0 N(d_1) - L e^{-rt}N(d_2) \\ 
 \sigma_E E_0 = N(d_1) \sigma_V V_0
\end{cases}
where $$d_2 = d_1 - \sigma_V \sqrt{t} = \frac{\log\frac{V_0}{K} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2t}{\sigma_V \sqrt{t}} - \sigma_V \sqrt{t}$$
But, using matlabs' ***fsolve*** function, even with feeding analytical Jacobian for different data inputs sometimes returns me:

**No solutions found.**
or
**Equation solved, fsolve stalled.**

This is even worse if I use more complex equations. 
Could somebody give some hint how to solve this system?

or Could somebody give tips, ideas or reference how to choose good initial conditions for ***fsolve***? 
Finally, I eager to be able to solve more complex model than the written above.

**Update:** I have been thinking to search for reference how to work with ill-posed problems, or trying to identify if condition number is good, this is still in progress.

Also I have been restating the problem as the minimisation of sum of squares, with some boundary conditions, but this performs not better.

Also I have pictured( but lost somewhere, so can not attach) the plot of the sum of squares of the above functions. Plot looks very flat, which I believe explains why this is difficult for solver to find global minimum.

Using ***fminsearch*** first and then feeding this result as initial condition to ***fmincon*** or ***fmin*** or ***fsolve*** will not work as ***fminsearch*** returns unreal numbers. **Update**: I did use function $$\min_x[y-f(x) ]$$
to minimize. I missed that it is not convex problem, squaring it I get reasonable results. Now I am trying further. 
Thanks!

Comment: The first equation does not involve $\sigma_V$, why don't you just solve it for $V_0$?

Comment: I am sorry, I have added what $d_1$ means now. The $\sigma_V$ is inside of $N(d_1)$ which is the cumulative distribution function of $d_1$.

Comment: Did you try changing the Algorithm and Tolerances of the solver?

Comment: @Ievgenii, yes, currently I use Levenberg Marquardt, which seems the most efficient, and TolX, TolFun are put to 1e-5, and MaxIter, MaxFunEvals are put to 10^5.